# Hibernate Distinct with order by

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

can anyone tell me how to use distinct with order by in HQL query.
I've been looking for a solution but can't seem to find exact one.
This is my HQL query

```
select distinct city 
from City city 
  where city.id is not null 
    and upper(city.name) != upper('Unknown')  
    and city.state.id =:stateId 
order by upper(trim(city.name))
```

Problem -  SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list.

Comment: Why do you have two orders by?

Comment: Ohoo Sorry I have just paste wrong query Let me correct first.

Comment: I am not an hibernate expert, but won't `select city 
from City city` return **all** columns from the table `city`? In that case the distinct makes no sense because the PK column will be part of the result.

Answer (score 2):

It does not make sense to order by a column which is not part of the selected `distinct` columns.

Since you are not joining with a collection, your records will be distinct anyway (at least PK will differ), you can just omit distinct:

```
select distinct city 
from City city 
  where city.id is not null 
    and upper(city.name) != upper('Unknown')  
    and city.state.id =:stateId 
order by upper(trim(city.name))
```

In general, when there really are duplicates in the result set and you want to eliminate them, you can achieve it with a subquery:

```
select city
from City city
  where city.id in (select c.id from City c join c.someCollection sc where ...)
order by upper(trim(city.name))
```

The other benefit of this approach is that it is probably better performance-wise, as `distinct`ing rows is usually an expensive operation in the database.

Comment: I don't need distinct keyword in my query so i have just removed it and now its working for me. Thanks a_horse and Thanks Dragan your solution may be help to other.

Comment: Sure it makes sense to order by a column which is not part of selected distinct columns. Say you have an entity, call it Account, and it encapsulates a related child object, Client, and you want to sort the Accounts by Client.name, but don't want to return Client.name as a field in the result set, you want only account fields, and say your query is such that it may potentially return duplicates, you would want to use distinct in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query. order by will not be double. you have to use it in a single. Hope it will help you.

**order by city.name it means it will be ascending order using cities name.**

```
select distinct city.name, city.id
from City city 
where city.id is not null 
and upper(city.name) != upper('Unknown') 
and city.state.id =:stateId 
order by upper(trim(city.name))
```

Comment: I need all columns from the table.

Comment: Yes Sky we can use this query by mention all the columns in with select but I think this it's not a good way, I don't want to mention all this columns.