# SELECT DISTINCT + ORDER BY in JPA 2 Criteria API

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I've a class `Lawsuit`, that contains a `List<Hearing>`, each one with a `Date` attribute.

I need to select all the `Lawsuit`s ordered by the date of their `Hearing`s

I've a CriteriaQuery like

```
CriteriaBuilder           cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Lawsuit>    cq = cb.createQuery(Lawsuit.class);
Root<Lawsuit>           root = cq.from(Lawsuit.class);
```

I use **distinct** to flatten the results:

```
cq.select(root).distinct(true);
```

I then **join** `Lawsuit` with `Hearing`

```
Join<Lawsuit, Hearing> hearing = root.join("hearings", JoinType.INNER);
```

to create `Predicate`s

```
predicateList.add(cb.isNotNull(hearing.<Date>get("date")));
```

and `Order`s:

```
orderList.add(cb.asc(hearing.<Date>get("date")));
```

Everything works fine if I avoid `distinct`, but if I use it, it complains about not being able to order based on fields that are not in the SELECT:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for `SELECT DISTINCT`, **`ORDER BY` expressions must appear in select list**

The `List<Hearing>` is already accessible through the `Lawsuit` classes returned, so I'm confused: **how should I add them to the select list ?**

Comment: Well, do you need a sub-select for the List<Hearing> and then maybe you can put the order by in the sub-select? I don't have time to look at it right now.

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas; how would you do the inner query with criteria api?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915532/4754790) might be helpful.

Comment: I don't use Criteria API, but it should be straightforward to write subqueries there also.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic: it should, I agree, but I've no clues on how to do it (for the select-ed fields with Criteria API). BTW I've found that the problem was in the joins (what a donk). Feel free to answer with something canonical and more general purpose on the distinct and joins (without involving Criteria API), and I'll award you the bounty. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've discovered the source of the problem somewhere else, and solving it has made unnecessary to do what asked in the question; 
as described in other answers, it should be unnecessary to perform the `distinct` here.

The duplicate rows were originated by erroneous `left join`s that were performed on collections (attributes of the root object) even if the predicates were not been used:

```
Join<Lawsuit, Witness> witnesses = root.join("witnesses", JoinType.LEFT);
if (witnessToFilterWith!=null) {
    predicateList.add(cb.equal(witnesses.<Long>get("id"),witnessToFilterWith.getId()));
}
```

The `join` should obviously be performed as `inner` and **only if needed**:

```
if (witnessToFilterWith!=null) {
    Join<Lawsuit, Witness> witnesses = root.join("witnesses", JoinType.INNER);
    predicateList.add(cb.equal(witnesses.<Long>get("id"),witnessToFilterWith.getId()));
}
```

So, if you're here because you're getting the same problem, **search the problem in the joins**.

Answer (score 4):

You can also de-duplicate via group by based on primary key column of root table:

```
 cq.groupBy(root.get("id")); // Assuming that Lawsuite.id is primary key column
```